# Как считать количество знаков препинания в файле с помощью функции?

Tags: c++

```
int countSigns(char (&ch)[100][50], int);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    char ch[100][50];
    int count;
    int numberMarks[100];
    int k = 0;
    ifstream myFileIf("C:\\Users\\evgen\\source\\repos\\Lab№3\\TextFile.txt", ios_base::app);
    if (!myFileIf.is_open())
        cout << "File cannot be open!\n";
    else {
        while (k != 100)
        {
            myFileIf.getline(ch[k], 100);
            k++;
        }
        myFileIf.close();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i = 100; i++)
    {
        numberMarks[i] = strlen(ch[i]);
    }
    count = countSigns(ch, numberMarks);
    cout << "\nThe number of punctuation mark: " << count << endl;
    return 0;
}

int countSigns(char(&ch)[100][50], int number[100])
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l <= number[j]; l++)
        {
            if (ch[j][l] == ',' || ch[j][l] == ':' || ch[j][l] == '!' || ch[j][l] == '?' ||
                ch[j][l] == '\'' || ch[j][l] == '"' || ch[j][l] == ')' || ch[j][l] == '(' || ch[j][l] == '-' ||
                ch[j][l] == ';')
                temp++;
            else if (ch[j][l] == '.')
            {
                if (ch[j][l] == '.' && ch[j][l+1] == '.' && ch[j][l+1] == '.')
                {
                    temp++;
                    l += 2;
                }
                else
                    temp++;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: [std::count?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

Comment: А считывать файл в массив обязательно? Почему бы просто не считывать по символу и проверять его?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку @EOF